# Form element deletion

Tags: forms, axapta

I want to delete unused elements form but I can not delete.
form a key sign off.
I wonder if that is due to me?
How can I remove it ?

[image]

Comment: I am afraid that your question is not so clear...

Comment: Please rephrase your question. Using Google Translate may give a more comprehensible result.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the image you put, it seems the element is locked. Do you have a version control system set up on your environment? If so, you may need to check out the object before being able to modify it.